# Raspberry pi - Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 - Can't install docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian, bullseye

I'm trying to install Docker on my Raspberry Pi:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

For that I am using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

But when I run the third command, I got:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: b2e29ef7a9a89840d2333637f7d1900a83e7153f
Warning: the "docker" command appears to already exist on this system.

If you already have Docker installed, this script can cause trouble, which is
why we're displaying this warning and provide the opportunity to cancel the
installation.

If you installed the current Docker package using this script and are using it
again to update Docker, you can safely ignore this message.

You may press Ctrl+C now to abort this script.
+ sleep 20
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sh -c mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && chmod -R 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings
+ sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/gpg" | gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c echo "deb [arch=armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian bullseye stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin >/dev/null
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already remove all the docker packages since when I run `dpkg -l | grep -i docker` I don't see any package and when I run `docker -version` I see `sudo: docker: command not found`.

What I am missing here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try running `type docker` and `sudo type docker` to see why the installation scripts thinks it's already installed.

Comment: running type docker I got: docker is hashed (/usr/local/bin/docker)

Comment: That means that if you run `docker`, your shell will actually try to run `/usr/local/bin/docker` so you have either omitted to remove that, or you have not rehashed your shell with `hash -r`.

Comment: I already run hash -r /usr/local/bin/docker and when I run "type docker" I already see "bash: type: docker: not found". But when I run sudo sh get-docker.sh I still got the "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." but now without the previous Warning: the "docker" command appears to already exist on this system.